# This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server toread from the conf db

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, sql

I am getting this error when i try to open our websites. Also we checked sql connection and passwords/usernames  I can connect to sql with this user and i can execute a query and select on db and there is no mistake. How can i check the connection or anything ? Also i checked SQL Management Studio and this user have sysadmin role.

[image]

Comment: Have you started the service "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"?

Comment: Yes. İt is working.

Comment: Could you ping sql server from SharePoint server?

Comment: Yes , it is working too.

Comment: Could it be the app pool account or the farm account password is expired?